# Simple Max Profit Scheduling Algo

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, scheduling

Assume that you have an array of durations L[5,8,2] with deadlines D[13,8,7].  If you have an end time of each activity E[i]. You receive (or lose) an amount D[i] - E[i] for each activity, which sums to a total amount gained or lost, which for this example is 4. `E` depends on what order you do each activity. For example if you do each L[i] in ascending order your resulting E would be [7,15,2].

I've found the max value occurs after you sort the `L` array, which runs O(nlog n). What's fascinating is that after you sort the `L` array, there's no need to sort the `D` array b/c you'll end up with the same max value for any arrangement of the deadlines (I've tried on larger sets).  Is there a better way to solve this problem to get the running time to be less than O(nlogn)?  I've spent a couple hours trying all sorts of linear tweaks on lengths and deadlines, to no avail, or even use conditional statements.  It seems to me this can be done in O(n) time, but I can't for the life of me find it.

Comment: Where is `E` array in the question?

Comment: `E` depends on what order you do each activity.  If you do each `L[i]` in ascending order your resulting `E` would be [7,15,2].

Comment: I added that to my question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorting the durations is the correct answer. As @liori points out, there are different ways to sort integers, but regardless, you still need to sort the durations.

Let's look at an abstraction of the problem. Start with `L[a,b,c]` and `D[x,y,z]`. Assume that the tasks are executed in the order given, then the end times are `E[a,a+b,a+b+c]`, and so

```
profit = (x - a) + (y - (a+b)) + (z - (a+b+c))
```

which is the same as

```
profit = x + y + z - 3a - 2b - c
```

From this, we can see that the order of the deadlines doesn't matter, but the order in which the tasks are executed is important. The duration of the first task is subtracted from the profit many times. But the duration of the last task is only subtracted from the profit once. So clearly, the tasks need to be done in order from shortest to longest.

Answer (score 1):

You sort an unbounded array of integers. There are faster ways to sort integers than the ones based on just comparing their magnitude: O(n log log n) for a deterministic case and O(n sqrt(log log n)) for a randomized algorithm. See https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/19089 for more discussion.

If the integers are bounded (as in, you can guarantee they won't be larger than some value), [counting sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) will solve the problem in O(n).